# How to manage an ansible project structure with exchangable inventories in git

Tags: git, ansible

I am working on some ansible playbooks that I am versioning via git. I would like to maintain the same roles and playbooks on two different servers (control nodes, for brevity: node-a and node-b), but have two independent inventories on these control nodes. These inventories need to be separated (i.e. the inventory for node-a should only be present on node-a and not be accessible from node-b and vice-versa). Currently my project structure is a variation of the [alternate best practices layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) as shown below:

```
ansible-project/ (git repo)
   ansible.cfg
   inventories/
       inventory-a
       inventory-b
   roles/
   playbooks/
```

Here, both inventory are still in the same folder in just one big git repository. I tried to move the inventories into their own repos to maintain them separately.

My initial plan was to make the `inventories` folder a submodule and add a different submodule on my two control nodes. This does not work, since submodules are also synchronized via git and thus the inventory from node-a would cross over to node-b and vice versa.

My second idea was to restructure the project as follows:

```
On both nodes:
ansible-project/ (git repo)
   ansible.cfg
   roles/
   playbooks/

On node-a:
inventory_node-a/ (git repo)
    inventory-a/

On node-b:
inventory_node-b/ (git repo)
    inventory-b
    ...
```

This would require major refactoring of the code and strays (even more) from the best practice project structure. However, it seems like the only usable way.

Is there an easier way to maintain two "replaceable" ansible inventories for one project with git? Is there a git feature I am missing that could help with this? Or is there a different structure I could adopt for the project?

Comment: Inventories are config files, just like any config files they must not be committed at all.

Comment: How do you want to tell ansible-playbook which inventory to use? In the playbook (e.g. *- hosts: node_a*)? In the config (e.g. *inventory = $PWD/inventories/hosts*)? ...

Comment: @VladimirBotka Currently I pass the path to the inventory via the CLI call to ansible-playbooks. The hosts/ groups are specified in the playbooks.

Comment: Then, you can link the particular directory (.e.g. *inventory_node-a*)  to the project (.e.g. *ansible-project/inventories*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up the helpful comments of phd and Vladimir Botka, I write this answer to mark this question closed. Thank you both for the feedback.

## Is it possible to manage inventories as asked?

Yes. Following Vladimir Botka's suggestion, you can create a folder structure where the inventory is an independent git repo somewhere on the control node. For example on node-a, this would look as follows:

```
inventory_node-a/ (git repo)
    inventory-a/

ansible-project/ (git repo)
    .gitignore
    ansible.cfg
    inventories/
        inventory-a (symlink to ../../inventory_node-a/)
    roles/
    playbooks/
```

You will need to add a `.gitignore` file to the `ansible-project` repo to ignore the subfolder `inventories/inventory-a` so it does not show up a changed file.

## Should I do that?

Ultimately, we went with phd's suggestion and removed all inventories from the repository. This saved us a lot of hassle and complicated structures.

We retained one entry in the inventory for minimal testing purposes, added the inventory folder to `.gitignore`, and manage the inventories on each host independently.